# Voting on a post having viewed up/down votes

Tags: support, voting, vote-count

#### Steps to reproduce behaviour:

1. Click a post's score to display the up and down votes.
2. Vote either up or down on that post.

#### Expected result:

The updated up/down votes (with my vote counted) is displayed.

#### Actual result:

Only the post score (with my vote counted) is displayed.

---

Is this by design, or something that could be requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is by-design. There's nothing restricting you from clicking post's score again, but I think that when you click upvote or downvote, you already know number of upvotes and/or downvotes.

Comment: True, the fact that the up/down disappears isn't like i'm loosing info (as you say, i've just seen the votes!), but it looks a little odd having it change back from a UI point of view (IMO).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: On that logic i would say it is also odd that you cannot switch back by clicking it again.

Comment: @H.B.: Agreed.. Ideally i'd like voting to preserve whether up/down or just score is shown, as well as clicking on the up/down votes making it revert back to store (as i understand your comment above).

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's by design, as that is the only way to make the count of the up-votes and down-votes disappear, without to refresh the full page.